# Extracting `<key>=<value>` pairs with regex, dot group (.+?) not cooperating with optional space (\s)

Tags: regex, pcre

I have this string:

```
metadata=1.2 name=stone:supershare UUID=eff4e7bc:47aea5cf:0f0560f0:2de38475
```

I wish to extract from it the key and value pairs: `<key>=<value>`.

```
/(\w+)=(.+?)\s/g
```

This, as expected, doesn't return the `UUID` pair, due to not being followed by space:

```
[
    "metadata=1.2 ",
    "name=stone:supershare "
],
[
    "metadata",
    "name"
],
[
    "1.2",
    "stone:supershare"
]
```

Now, obviously, we should make the `\s` lookup optional:

```
/(\w+)=(.+?)\s?/g
```

Though, this goes utterly nuts extracting only the first symbol from `value`:

```
[
    "metadata=1",
    "name=s",
    "UUID=e"
],
[
    "metadata",
    "name",
    "UUID"
],
[
    "1",
    "s",
    "e"
]
```

I am kind of lost, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `\s` isn't required, the previous part `(.+?)` is free to match just one character which is what it will try to do because of the `?`. You can either:

- change `(.+?)` to `(.+)` but that might cause other issues if your values can include spaces or
- change `\s?` to `(?:\s|$)`

Comment: Bah, attempted a `\s|$`, but yes, without parentheses. This feels more readable.

Comment: You're right, I should've used the non-capturing parens. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

@acfrancis explanation is correct, on the other hand you can try the following:

```
/(\w+)=([^\s]+)/g
```

This matches the `<key>` using `(\w+)` as in you original expression, but then it matches the value using `([^\s]+)` which consumes one or more characters that are not white spaces.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uB4sI9)